# How to use node (e.g. RGB curve) to directly modify texture

Tags: texturing, materials, shaders

I have a simple node shading setup like this:

[image]

Is it possible to "apply" this RGB Curve node to the texture? In other words, I want to modify the texture itself, so that the final result will be the same without RGB Curve node.

I know I can do this with curve tool in Photoshop or other image editors. But my question is how to do this in Blender?

Comment: You need to bake the texture I guess

Comment: @moonboots afaik backing texture takes the final render result into account right? But I don't want the lighting/shadow/AO etc.

Comment: Bake the `Emit` type and use an `Emission` node in the node setup (replaces the Principled BSDF).